# set app to bypass full tunnel VPN?

Tags: network, vpn

I'm connected to ethernet on my work computer, all the traffic is sent to a full tunnel IPsec VPN.

I'm trying to find a way to set some app e.g a specific web browser to go through the LAN / or WiFI instead of IPsec

I'm using Little Snitch which create a virtual interface in order to pre-block some traffic so I assume this would be possible.

any idea?

Comment: What you need is Split Tunnelling - see https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/57846/routing-all-traffic-except-a-few-ip-ranges-though-default-gateway-in-mountain-li

Comment: yes that would have been perfect, but I can't change the full tunnel, it's setup my my work through MDM :(

Comment: As far as I'm aware, that's the only way to do it. If it's governed by MDM, I'd be very wary of trying to hack around it, the company may not be best pleased.

Comment: yes you right, I better forgot about it and just use the full tunnel / or use a personal computer for the rest. thank you anyway